# How to filter out whole set of batch records in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table say table A and it has below two columns,

```
Id                  Description
------------------------------------------------------
12534554   Item created
12534554   Item assigned to team
12534554   Item fixed
12534554   Item removed from batch
16733686   Item created
16733686   Item assigned to team
18667456   Item assigned to team
```

Whenever I find the keyword '**Item removed from batch**' in description field, I want to filter out the whole batch and the result should be as below,

```
Id                  Description
-----------------------------------------
16733686   Item created
16733686   Item assigned to team
18667456   Item assigned to team
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using correlated subquery -

```
select id,Description from tablename t
where not exits 
    (select 1 from tablename t1 where t.id=t1.id and description='Item removed from batch')
```

Comment: Does this filter out the whole batch ?

Comment: @bhakum3, have you executed it? It should be filtered out the whole

Comment: I have verified with other set of records. It works fine. Now. Thanks

Comment: @bhakum3, if it helped u please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the whole batch.

```
select id, Description from table
where id not in(
select id from table description ='Item removed from batch'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, this might be faster using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when description = 'Item removed from batch' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as num_removals
      from t
     ) t
where num_removals = 0;
```